# DSum() domain as subquery?

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, subquery

I run this query:

```
SELECT
job_code_desc,
SumOfDowntime AS DowntimeTotal,
Round(DSum("[SumofDowntime]","DT","[SumOfDowntime]>=" & [DowntimeTotal] & "")/DSum("[SumOfdowntime]","DT"),3) AS CumPct

FROM
  (SELECT 
  pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc, 
  Sum(pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.downtime) AS SumOfDowntime

  FROM 
  pareto_downtime_detail_tbl

  WHERE
  (((pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) Not Like "*break*" 
  AND (pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) Not Like "*prep*"))

  GROUP BY 
  pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) AS DT;
```

and get an error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or
>   query 'DT'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled
>   correctly."

Can the domain for a `DSum()` function be from a subquery?  Or must it call from a "permanent" table or query?  When I save the subquery (DT) as a permanent query and run the query above,

```
SELECT 
pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry.job_code_desc, 
pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry.SumOfdowntime AS DowntimeTotal, 
Round(DSum("[SumofDowntime]","pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry","[SumOfDowntime]>=" & [DowntimeTotal] & "")/DSum("[SumOfdowntime]","pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry"),3) AS CumPct

FROM 
pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry;
```

it runs successfully but at a noticeable performance lag.  I then used the new query, `pareto_lift_downtime_detail_qry`, as a make-table query and then referenced this new table.  This does what I want, at an appropriate speed, but I have 2 reasons to not utilize make-table queries.  I want to keep this file as organized as possible, and this data will be refreshed weekly by a clerk with little Access knowledge and zero experience with queries/databases, so she will not be making new make-table queries every week.

Comment: re: "this data will be refreshed weekly by a clerk with little Access knowledge and zero experience with queries/databases, so she will not be making new make-table queries every week" - That won't be necessary if you build her a Macro or a Form with a "Weekly Refresh" button that invokes the required code to get the job done.

Comment: I suppose I didn't think you could use a macro for repeated make-table queries of the same name.  Writing the VB code for this from scratch is more than my weary mind can muster--I'll play around with the macros and see where I can get.

Answer (score 1):

*"Can the domain for a DSum() function be from a subquery?"*

No.

*"Or must it call from a "permanent" table or query?"*

Yes.

Comment: @TrevorD Sorry, this answer is so skimpy, but I got lost trying to figure out exactly what you want your query to do.  If you post samples of starting data and your desired output from that sample, we can probably get you a workable query.

Comment: On the other hand, Gord's suggestion is solid.  Give the user a hand-holdy method to reload the DT table whenever needed.  An advantage there is you may be able index that table to speed up the final query.